# How can I set the value of a field located in a subform equal to a field on the main form after update?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am creating a form using Access 2010 to update a table. I have a field, Start Date, in a subform. This is set to required in the table properties. I have a field for the End Date outside of the subform. When a user enters a Start Date, the End Date should automatically populate with this same value.

I tried the following, but I am receiving the message "You must enter a value in Position.StartDate' field.

```
Private Sub StartDate_AfterUpdate()
If Not IsNull(Me.StartDate) Then
Me.StartDate = Me.EndDate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The main form is the *parent*:

```
Private Sub StartDate_AfterUpdate()

    If Not IsNull(Me!StartDate.Value) Then
        Me.Parent!EndDate.Value = Me!StartDate.Value
    End If

End Sub
```